# How do I make sure that gems get installed in the correct location?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

### Setup

- Fresh Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS install (in HyperV with a snapshot to first reboot)
- sudo apt-get update
- official rvm install

  - both single and multi-user
- rvm install [ruby]

  - 2.1 and 2.2 separately (on fresh installs)
- GEM_HOME: /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 (for 2.2 install)

pre `gem update` gem location example:

```
/home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4
```

post `gem update` gem location example:

```
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.9.2
```

After the first `gem update --system` and `gem update` an attempt to `gem clean` *always* ends with errors that updated gems' previous versions are not installed in GEM_HOME.

Everything else that I've tested with the rvm/ruby setup is functioning (single or multiuser installs).

Comment: This is not an answer to my own question, but I discovered (being new to rvm) something called gemsets. There's an @global gemset that seems to be the one that needed the cleaning.